# get the highest value via jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I get the highest (name)value of these radio-inputs?

```
<div class="anything">
    <input type="radio" name="grd_10" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_10" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_10" >
</div>

<div class="anything">
    <input type="radio" name="grd_11" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_11" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_11" >
</div>

<div class="anything">
    <input type="radio" name="grd_20" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_20" >
    <input type="radio" name="grd_20" >
</div>
```

So in this example I want to get the value "20", as this is the highest value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var highest = Math.max.apply(Math, $('input[type=radio]').map(function() {
   return +this.name.replace('grd_', '');
}).get());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var highest=$('.anything input').map(function () {
    return $(this).attr('name').split('grd_')[1];
}).sort().get().pop();
```